# redirect all unauthorized users to unauthorized view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization, .net-5

We build an application that at the moment the Identity is not implemented.

As temporary quickfix, I would like to redirect all unauthorised users to a Unauthorized page.

It works for the HomeController, but I would like to implement a middleware or somthing that would check it globally for all controllers

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserResolverService _userService;

    public HomeController(IUserResolverService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        if (_userService.GetCurrentUser() == null) // unauthorized user
            return View("Unauthorized");

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly, but as quickfix, I managed up in the `_Layout.cshtml` to redirect to `Home` controller's `Index` action like this:

```
@inject IUserResolverService userService
@{
    var currentUser = userService.GetCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser == null) {
        Context.Response.Redirect("/");
        return;
    }
```